# Creating a new table with a column for count of values for another column

Tags: sql, group-by, count, nested, where-in

I have a table aisle_list that has columns order_id and aisle_id. 
 
Below is an example:

```
order_id aisle_id
1        21
1        24
1        83
1        95
1        108
1        120
36       0 
36       2
```

I want to create a new table with a column that lists the count of the count of unique aisle_ids for each order_id where the count is 4, 5, or 6. So I need to have a nested select with one group by.

```
CREATE TABLE sample_path AS
SELECT a.order_id, a.aisle_id, x.count_num_aisles
FROM aisle_list as a, 
(SELECT count(*) as count_num_aisles FROM aisle_list
GROUP BY order_id) as x
WHERE count_num_aisles IN (4, 5, 6);
```

Desired result:

```
order_id aisle_id count_num_aisles
1        21       6
1        24       6
1        83       6
1        95       6
1        108      6
1        120      6
```

The query is taking forever to run. Can someone offer a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `group by` and `having`?

```
SELECT a.order_id, count(distinct aisle_id) as num_aisles
FROM aisle_list a
GROUP BY a.order_id
HAVING count(distinct aisle_id) BETWEEN 4 and 6;
```

Comment: A much easier solution! I just started with SQL so I'm still learning. Thank you.